# Django with text editor

Tags: python, django, text-editor

So, I'm going through the Django [tutorial01](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/) off their website, and I'm stuck with the stupidest thing there is: I don't know how to 'connect' any text editor with the code I'm working with. I realize that, for this to resemble the command line, I should be using Python's IDLE (or I am mistaken?). It is, of course, much more convenient than typing my first Django project in command prompt... Can anyone tell me what-to-open-with-what for this to work? :)

... Much obliged.

SOLUTION: Code snippets are written in separated boxes with a header. In it, a path and a file name are displayed. Open that file in your text editor.

Answer (score 0):

My personal best Python/Django IDE so far is Pycharm.
https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/
Note: Only professional version supports Django.

Comment: Yes, it was already recommended to me, but that's not the issue. I need an editor capable of executing a command on input, something similar to IDLE, and, firstly, I don't know how to import my Django project into any text editor. I simply don't know what file to open for editing.

Comment: Highly recommend you to go back to the tutorial and start reading again. Your problem seems really vague to me.

Comment: If you read the tutorial, you might have noticed that the command examples are made to look like that they've been typed it cmd, only to switch to regular Python syntax on the topic of creating models. But I've figured it out somehow.